# attempting to show the 'name' instead of the 'id' in MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple form which displays user details and joins the username from a separate table. 
In the user table in mysql i have the following columns 'user_record_id', 'forename', 'surname', 'email', 'role_type_code'
In the login_details table i have the following columns 'username, password, user_record_id'

The 'role_type_code' in the users table is a foreign key to the role_type table which holds the following columns 'role_type_code' and 'role_title'.

I am trying to display the 'role_title' instead of the code however I'm not sure how to go about this using tables.

I have previously done this using a drop down list but I'm not sure how to applying the same logic to this table:

```
<select name="role">
      <?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $role['role_type_code'] ?>"><?php echo $role['role_title'] ?></option>
      <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
```

this is the form:

```
<?php

    include "db_conx.php";

    try {

        $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

        $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN login_details ON user.user_record_id=login_details.user_record_id ORDER BY user.surname');
        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>

    <h4><center>Manage Users</center></h4>

    <div class="container">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div id = "table_container" style="width:auto; margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        User Record ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Forename
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Surname
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Email
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Role Type
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Username
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- populating the table with information from mysql database -->
                                <?php foreach ($users as $row) {
                                    echo "<tr><td>";
                                    echo $row['user_record_id'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo $row['forename'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo $row['surname'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo $row['email'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo $row['role_type_code'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo $row['username'];
                                    echo "</td><td>";
                                    echo "</tr>"; }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

any help would be much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the query to:

```
SELECT u.*, l.*, r.role_title  FROM user u
INNER JOIN login_details l USING (user_record_id)
LEFT JOIN role_type r USING (role_type_code)
ORDER BY u.surname
```

Then you can output:

```
 echo $row['role_title'];
```

Comment: @user90210 Sure, its using table aliases so that you don't have to type the full name of the tables out. Also it enables you to select exactly which fields you want from each table and can help avoid conflicts where there are two fields with the same name in different tables

Comment: brilliant. i may start using them for the rest of my forms, seems like such a simple approach! thanks again :D